# Calling a registered RPC method on same server in Golang

Tags: go, json-rpc

I have some methods registered to a type in server program for RPC in Golang. I want to use those methods from clients as well as the server itself. e.g. I have an addition method registered as RPC method which I want to invoke from clients. But I want to call the same method in the same server program for some other function too. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you willing to suffer the overhead of RPC even when calling it from the server itself? If you are you can just open a local connection to `localhost` and use it as a client would.

Comment: Alternatively, if those shared methods are the same, put them together in a package, and have both your RPC server and your other application install/use that package.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer, if we don't know how you build your code with some exemple it will be easier.

Two choices.
Create client with goroutine, set your connection to the server and call the method. This method is bad, wtf.

Second :

```
type CalcServ struct {
  LastAnswer
}

type CalcReq struct {
   X int
   Y int
}

type CalcResp struct {
   Z int
}

func (serv *CalcServ) Add(req *CalcReq, resp *CalcResp) error {
  serv.LastAnswer = req.X + req.Y
  serv.Show(req, resp)
  return nil
}

func (serv *CalcServ) Show(req *CalcReq, resp *CalcResp) error {
  resp.Z = serv.LastAnswer
  return nil
}
```

My exemple is not a good implementation, but it's just to show the idea to you.
There are Two RPC method, `Add` and `Show`, and `Add` call `Show`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this myself.  This is a contrived example showing what I did in my case:

This is the RPC function...

```
func (server *Server) RemoteGoroutineCount(request GoroutineCountsRequest, response *GoroutineCountsResponse) error {
    response.Count = runtime.NumGoroutine()
    return nil
}
```

Now, if I want to call that locally, I can just do

```
req := GoroutineCountsRequest{}
res := &GorouteCountsResponse{}
s := &Server{}
err := s.RemoteGoroutineCount(req, res)
// handle error
// Now res has your filled in response
res.NumGoroutines
```